# Visual Studio MacOS - How to exclude Exception scenario

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, debugging, exception

I want to break on all exceptions except for certain scenarios. I need to get access to the Exception variable being thrown in the condition expression so I can exclude cases. I'm guessing that I can access the exception variable in the condition expression in the image below, but I'm not sure what the exception variable name will be when the code hits this point. I've tried a few permutations like 'exception' but, the debugger just doesn't break.

[image]

***What is the variable name for the exception here?***

Comment: That's the condition you put there with respect to the place in code where you are placing the break point. When you debug the code, if this condition is true at runtime the debugger will stop at the break point else it will skip the break point.

Comment: Understood. What is the variable name for the exception being caught?

Comment: I am not sure what does that mean... The variable name will be there in the code. You need to use that variable name in the condition here. Such as `ex is ArgumentNullException` where ex is the exception variable in your code.

Comment: You're not understanding what I am asking. If I wrap the code in a try/catch to get a variable name such as "ex" it's already too late. I need to know how to access the exception variable that is being caught in the debugger. Perhaps it doesn't have a name and I can't access it... If so, I can't actually exclude exceptions in scenarios without modifying the code. This would be a big flaw in the MacOS debugger.